# Ind function for KNN

Tags: r, knn

it's my first contact with R (or any other language) and i'm trying to understand these rows for a KNN project:

```
#Data partition
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = T, prob (0.7, 0.3))

training <- data [ind == 1,]

test <- data [ind == 2,]
```

The first row is telling me that will be created one sample that contains values (1 or 2) with replacement and 70% of my data size, and the other one with 30%, right?

If so, what's the point of ind == 1 in my training object or ind == 2 on my test object?

Comment: `Error in prob(0.7, 0.3) : could not find function "prob"`. Please add which packages you're using.

Comment: you will  use `ind ` to extract original value from from `data` in each split.